# CSS Framework for a width of 972px?

Tags: html, layout, css

I'm working to create a website with a CSS width of 972px. Normally I use blueprint which has a width of 950. Is there a better CSS framework avaialble that works well with 972 w/o having to hack at it?

Thanks

Comment: You can use 960 grid and do a custom 61*12 layout.  http://960.gs and http://spry-soft.com/grids/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

generate one, adjust the gutters and stuff using this:
http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/gs01.php?GridWidth=972&GridColumns=12&GridMarginLeft=10&GridMarginRight=10

or for a 970px grid: http://thesquaregrid.com/

Comment: The Square Grid looks interesting but where do you see how to set it to 970? I see 994 pixels only . Not much documentation...

Answer (score 1):

It's been some time since I used blueprint, but I think that the grid layout is pretty customisable, isn't it? There should be some ruby script in the distribution that generates the css files for a custom width and column count.

And there's [Blueprinter](http://ianli.com/blueprinter/).

Answer (score 1):

The Golden Grid has 970px width http://code.google.com/p/the-golden-grid/